# How to show the solution of $\dot{x} = Ax $ is an invariant subspace?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, dynamical-systems

Consider the linear dynamical system $\dot{x} = Ax $ in $V$ a finite dimensional vector space.

The definition of an invariant subspace $U$ is as follows:

For all $x_0 \in U$, (initial condition), the solution $x(t)$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ lies in $U$, i.e. $x(t) \in U$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Intuitively, it means if we start in a subspace we never leave that subspace.

Prove that a subspace $U \subset V$ is an invariant subspace if and only if $AU \subset U$.

Comment: I think you want to say $AU \subset U$, since $AU \subset V$ is *always* true.  What do you think?  Cheers?

Comment: I added the "ordinary-differential-equations" tag to your post.

Comment: I fact I edited your post in accord with my first comment.  Hope that's OK.  If I'm wrong, change it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the linear, constant coefficient differential equation

$\dot x = Ax, \tag 1$

it is well-known that the solution with

$x(0) = x_0 \tag 2$

is

$x(t) = e^{At}x_0; \tag 3$

now if

$AU \subset U, \tag 4$

and

$x_0 \in U, \tag 5$

then

$Ax_0 \in U, \tag 6$

and indeed, for any non-negative $k \in \Bbb Z$,

$A^kx_0 \in U \tag 7$

as well; thus

$e^{At}x_0 = \left (\displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{A^k t^k}{k!} \right ) x_0 = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{t^k A^k x_0}{k!} \in U, \; \forall t \in \Bbb R, \tag 8$

since the series on the right converges to an element in $U$, a closed sub-space, being finite dimensional.

Now suppose every solution initialized at $x_0 \in U$ remains in $U$ for all $t$; then

$x(t) = e^{At}x_0 \in U, \; \forall t \in \Bbb R; \tag 9$

since $U$ is a linear subspace of $V$, the tangent vector to any curve in $U$ is also in $U$, whence

$\dot x(t) = Ae^{At}x_0 \in U, \forall t \in \Bbb R; \tag{10}$

setting $t = 0$ yields

$Ax_0 = Ae^{A(0)}x_0 = \dot x(0) \in U; \tag{11}$

but since $x_0 \in U$ is arbitrary, we have

$AU \subset U, \tag{12}$

and we are done.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: does that mean if the solutions evolves in the eigenvector direction, it will become invariant ?

Comment: @Darthsid1995:  if $Ax = \mu x$ then $e^{At}x = e^{\mu t}x$, so yes, these solutions don't *become* invariant, they *are* invariant.

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Is there any other way to get $(12)$ other than tangent vector notion?

Comment: @Saeed:  not sure, but whatever notion works, it will mos' likely be related to the tangent vectors of solution curves I think; you have to somehow get from $e^{At}x_0 \subset U$ to $AU \subset U$, and that's the only way I know . ..